# Set count variable where it where

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

I have made this simple content rotator with jQuery which works fine, but as you can see I have made a mouseenter function  so that the rotator stops if your mouse in on the rotator.

My problem is that if I mouseenter and leave the function *rotateReview()* is restarted and the count variable (number) is 1. So automatically my rotator starts at the beginning where he should continue to the next one.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="review_rotator">
   <div class="rotator">
      <article>Content</article>
      <article>Content</article>
      <article>Content</article>
      <article>Content</article>
   </div><!--End .rotator-->
</div><!--End #review_rotator-->
```

**jQuery**

```
function rotateReview() {
    var turn = $('#review_rotator article');
    var numbers = turn.length;
    var number = 1;
    intv = setInterval(function() {
        number++;
        turn.fadeOut(300);
        $('#review_rotator article:nth-child('+number+')').fadeIn(200);
        if(numbers == number)
            number = 0;
    }, 4500)
}
rotateReview();

$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '#review_rotator article', function(e) {
    var mEnt = e.type == 'mouseenter';
    if(mEnt) {
        clearInterval(intv);
    } else {
        rotateReview();
    }
})
```

Comment: Well then either keep that value outside of the function (global variable f.e., or store it somewhere else, like a `data` attribute on the element itself) – or implement it as an object, that stores the necessary values and provides _methods_ to “pause” and resume the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you run `rotateReview`, the variable `number` will be assigned value 1. So you should store it outside the function or somewhere else, so that the variable `number` won't be freed after the function `rotateReview` finished.

I'will give 2 solutions.

#### 1. As a global variable

```
var number = 1;

function rotateReview() {
    var turn = $('#review_rotator article');
    var numbers = turn.length;

    intv = setInterval(function() {
        number++;
        turn.fadeOut(300);
        $('#review_rotator article:nth-child('+number+')').fadeIn(200);
        if(numbers == number)
            number = 0;
    }, 4500)
}
```

#### 2. Store in the closure

If you don't like global variable, you can store it in a closure, which is a immediately-invoked function.

```
var rotateReview  = (function () {
    var number = 1;

    return function () {
        var turn = $('#review_rotator article');
        var numbers = turn.length;

        intv = setInterval(function() {
            number++;
            turn.fadeOut(300);
            $('#review_rotator article:nth-child('+number+')').fadeIn(200);
            if(numbers == number)
                number = 0;
        }, 4500)
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
function rotateReview() {
    var turn = $('#review_rotator article');
    intv = setInterval(function() {
        var next = ($('#review_rotator article[style*="display: block"]')).next()[0];
        if(next == undefined)
            next = turn[0];
        console.log(next);
        turn.fadeOut(300);
        $(next).delay(300).fadeIn(200);
    }, 1000)
}
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/b53t39u7/